# Android - Parse - deleteInBackground, record not being deleted

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse with Android in order to sync my data.
I'm trying to delete an object which is stored in the Parse cloud via 
The callback returns and there's no exception, the Logcat message is "deleted".

But the object still exists in table when I check the Parse Data.

**tastToEdit** is an object from Task class (configured locally in my app).

```
    ParseObject parse_task = new ParseObject("Task");
    parse_task.put("Description",tastToEdit.getDescription());
    parse_task.put("DueDate",tastToEdit.getDueDate());
    parse_task.put("Priority",tastToEdit.getPriority().ordinal());
    int com_state = (tastToEdit.getCompleted()) ? 1 : 0;
    parse_task.put("IsCompleted",com_state);
    parse_task.put("Location",0);
    parse_task.put("Category",tastToEdit.getTask_catg().ordinal());
    parse_task.put("Status", tastToEdit.getTask_sts().ordinal());
    //parse_task.deleteInBackground();
    parse_task.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("msg","deleted");
            } else {
                Log.d("msg", "not deleted");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

What might be causing the callback to return as "deleted" but the object still remains?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new ParseObject and you try to delete it after but you don't provide an ObjectID.

A better way to do this will be to first do a ParseQuery for that task you are looking and the in the completion delete it.